# Is 'crewing' only about seamen?

Tags: meaning, expressions, word-usage

Is 'crewing' mainly about seamen or can it also be used as a general synonym of staffing, hiring, recruiting, employing, etc?

I want to use it in a sentence like 'the art of crewing' or 'crewing art' as in 'hiring people is difficult task - it's an art'.

Comment: Crew: A crew is a body or a class of people who work at a common activity, generally in a structured or hierarchical organization. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew

Comment: @Josh61 yes, i know there are different kind of crews. but when i asked google about form 'crewing' it returned see-related stuff. that's why i'm asking

Comment: Are you asking about *crew* as a verb?

Comment: To crew:( int. verb)
: *to act as a member of a crew*.
(transitive verb)
: *to serve as a crew member on (as a ship or aircraft)*


--She spent a couple of years crewing on a British ship. 
--The ship was crewed by 12 men.                                     http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crew

Comment: @Josh61 i edited question and added more information

Comment: You hire a crew member. *The art of crewing*  refers to making a group of people e real and succesful team. In that respect it may be used  referring to other contexts like: *The Fine Art Of Crewing A Movie* http://www.bobdegus.com/the-fine-art-of-crewing-a-movie/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crewing and Crewed are modernly used for various sorts of "team effort" machinery.
If you google "crew served" and "crewing -boat -naval" you'll see various examples. For obvious reasons most of these will be military usage, but are not strictly naval. You can also find some examples of industry usage regarding teams that are assigned to large-scale equipment.

Strictly speaking there's no argument against the way you would like to use the phrase, it's just not going to be universally familiar. For example it's a fine alternative to "manning" if you think people are squeamish about using that word (... they shouldn't be).

Interestingly [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crew&allowed_in_frame=0) shows that the origin of the word is rooted firmly in recruitment.

crew (n.) mid-15c., "group of soldiers," from Middle French crue (Old French creue) "an increase, recruit, military reinforcement," from fem. past participle of creistre "grow," from Latin crescere "arise, grow" (see crescent). Meaning "people acting or working together" is first attested 1560s. "Gang of men on a warship" is from 1690s. Crew-cut first attested 1938, so called because the style originally was adopted by boat crews at Harvard and Yale.

Comment: Good search suggestions.